# Calabash test system dialog is showing & interact with it

Tags: android, ruby, calabash, calabash-android

My android app project programmatically starts system dialog to install trusted CA certificate:

```
Intent intent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_PKCS12, certificate);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

This code pops up the system dialog as showing below:
[image]

Above thing is about my Android app project. Now, about test:

I am using [Calabash](http://calaba.sh/) to write automated acceptance tests for my project.

I know Calabash provids [pre-defined step definitions](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/canned_steps.md). But those steps provide keywords to interact with app's UI components (e.g. input text, press button). I **can't** find how to use those pre-defined steps to test whether the **system dialog** is showing.

**My questions:**

**Q1.** How to use Calabash pre-defined step definitions to check the system dialog is showing? How to input text into the dialog?

**Q2.** If answer to **Q1** is "it's impossible", then, how can I use Calabash to test it? Looks like I need to write my own Ruby function to 
    test it? If so, how to write Ruby function to test this system dialog is showing & how to interact with the system dialog in test with Calabash?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write your code for that. Assuming this is a default alert dialog:

This will assert if an view of the type AlertDialog is visible.

```
def check_if_dialog_open
   check_element_exists('*AlertDialog')
end
```

This will input some text to the first EditText if finds and hide the keyboard after.

```
def input_into_dialog(some_text)
    enter_text("android.widget.EditText *", some_text)
    hide_soft_keyboard
end
```

You could then write your own step for that:

```
Then(/^I check if my dialog is open and input some text$/) do
  check_if_dialog_open

  input_into_dialog('my text')

  sleep(STEP_PAUSE)
end
```

To input in that dialog you could query for an EditText visible.

It's just a matter of refining your queries. You can confirm if this is a default Android's AlertDialog using calabash console.

Learn more about console and query syntax [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/wiki/05-Query-Syntax) and check for more about Ruby API go [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/documentation/ruby_api.md).

Comment: thanks. But how can I figure out what is the name of the system dialog? Or do you mean `*AlertDialog` can be used which can match any system dialog currently showing on the screen?

Comment: Yes this was a generic example... But unless theres a hidden dialog it will work. If you want to improve need to you need to filter your query based on the calabash console output... Enter calabash console... Use query("*") to bring all the elements... Look for something that can identify your dialog... Like a text property and add it to the query.

Comment: I did some search, many people say that system UI elements are invisible to calabash...do I misunderstand something?

Comment: Were you able to list it in Calabash console?

Comment: I use calabash-android query, I can only see app's UI elements, there is no system UI elements listed.